# in_app_purchase event chart not showing Android platform

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, in-app-purchase, firebase-analytics

I have a Flutter app that has in-app purchases, and both iOS and Android are working well. **I have enabled Google Play integration for my Firebase**, so I receive information about my users' purchases. For iOS, it populates the `in_app_purchase` as it should.

However, when I look at the event chart and try to see the separate line for Android/iOS platform, only the iOS line is visible. The Android line remains flat, even though the difference between the "All" and "iOS" counts is exactly the one the Android line should have.

[image]

**Do you know what might be the problem?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone experiencing the same issue, this is a Firebase/Google Analytics problem. I began collecting all my data using BigQuery and created my own dashboards and charts. BigQuery contained all the necessary information to accurately display the chart of in-app purchases divided by platform.